# Autogenerate python docstrings in Visual Studio Express 2013

Tags: python, visual-studio-express, docstring, ptvs

Is there a way to automatically generate docstrings for python in Visual Studio Express 2013? If I remember correctly, in PyCharm if you type """ after a function/class header it automatically generates a docstring somewhat like the following:

```
def foo(a,b):
    """
    :param a:
    :param b:
    :return:
    """
```

Ideally, I would also like to be able to edit the template/profile for the generated docstrings.

Comment: You should file a feature request for this at https://github.com/Microsoft/ptvs/issues

Comment: It has already been raised: https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/820

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=njpwerner.autodocstring

It is a python docstring generator for VSCode. I did not test it, nor did I verify whether it works for Visual Studio Express 2013, but the image seems to show the functionality of auto generating docstrings.

For completeness, you could also automatically generate (and update) python docstrings (independent of Visual Studio Express 2013) with pyment.